# How to invalidate session when the time ends while using Server Sent Events?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, server-sent-events

I'm using Server Sent Events to send notifications and its working great , and the servlet that listens to events has these parameters

```
request.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);
AsyncContext context = request.startAsync();
context.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

my question is why the session not ending after the specified time ends ? this problem happened after I added this servlet to the application , if the servlet is the cause of it .. how to modify the servlet or what should I do to solve this problem ?